# Why getting error in initializing foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I am getting an error in initializing foreign key from teacher_detils table. Here I am using sql-server for database

Error is - There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'teacher_details' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_exam_details'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 43
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

```
create table teacher_details(
    teacher_user_id varchar(30) not null,
    teacher_name varchar(60) not null,
    teacher_email varchar(50) not null,
)

/*Alter teacher_details table for primary key*/


alter table teacher_details
add constraint pk_teacher_details primary key (teacher_user_id, teacher_email)

/* Table for exam */

create table exam_details(
    exam_id varchar(30) not null,
    teacher_user_id varchar(30) not null,
)

/* edited the drop table command to avoid confusion*/

/*Alter exam_details for primary key*/

alter table exam_details
add constraint fk_exam_details FOREIGN KEY (teacher_user_id)
    REFERENCES teacher_details(teacher_user_id)
```

Comment: In the last statement, you have already dropped exam_details table. So alter table query do not have a table to run on.

Comment: I have initialised techer_user_id as primary key in teacher_details table.

Comment: Drop command was for dropping table because there was an error.
After that I have created the table and then applied the constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to refer a non-PK column teacher_user_id in the foreign key since, the teacher_details had a composite key of two columns - id and email.

If a teacher_user_id can have multiple email_id, then I would suggest you to have teacher id PK in your teacher_details table.

```
create table teacher_details(
    teacher_user_id varchar(30) not null,
    teacher_name varchar(60) not null
)

/*Alter teacher_details table for primary key*/


alter table teacher_details
add constraint pk_teacher_details primary key (teacher_user_id)
```

and create a separate table to hold email for the teacher_user_id:

```
create table teacher_emails(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    teacher_user_id varchar(30) not null,
    teacher_email varchar(50) not null
)

alter table teacher_emails
add constraint fk_teacher_emails 
    FOREIGN KEY (teacher_user_id) REFERENCES teacher_details(teacher_user_id)
```

And now you can create this FK the way you were trying to do:

```
/* Table for exam */

create table exam_details(
    exam_id varchar(30) not null,
    teacher_user_id varchar(30) not null,
)

/* edited the drop table command to avoid confusion*/

/*Alter exam_details for primary key*/

alter table exam_details
add constraint fk_exam_details FOREIGN KEY (teacher_user_id)
    REFERENCES teacher_details(teacher_user_id)
```

If that is not the case i.e. **each user_id can have only one unique email** then no extra email table is needed. Just use:

```
create table teacher_details(
    teacher_user_id varchar(30) not null,
    teacher_name varchar(60) not null,
    teacher_email varchar(50) unique not null
)

alter table teacher_details
add constraint pk_teacher_details primary key (teacher_user_id)
```

Comment: When I will validate the register form for teachers in JSP then do I have to check in both tables teacher_details and teacher_tables?

Comment: Yes but that should be fine if you are worried about performance. Thing is teacher_user_id will probably be used many places and it's better to keep it as a PK

Comment: You mean to say that I will create a table to store teacher_details and another table to store email_id and password with teacher_user_id as foreign key?

Comment: @Dinesh - Yes if there can be multiple email per teacher_user_id. Isn't that why you were putting the email column in the PK constraint in the first place?

Comment: if I will use the unique constraint for teacher_email and primary key constraint for teacher_user_id then will it be appropiate?
Because teacher can update email as it is not the primary key.
If my project doesn't have the option to have multiple email id per user

Comment: @Dinesh In that case, it should be fine with one table. See the latest update in my answer.